# How to script django shell operations?

Tags: python, django, bash, shell, unix

I'd like to create a script (.sh or python, not important) that can do the following:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py shell
> from myapp.scenarios import *; reset_demo_data(); exit()
```

Line 1 to 3 are UNIX commands, but Line 4 is python to be executed in the opened Django shell.

I tried stuff with `|` and `>` to "inject" the python code in the command but nothing worked.
I guess it's quite easy to do but I can't figure out how..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can try this one line solution:

```
echo "from myapp.scenarios import *; reset_demo_data(); exit()" | python manage.py shell
```

You can add this line replacing Shell activation line.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the best option would be to write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Your script could then look like:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py shell
heroku run python manage.py reset_demo
```

when the management command is something like:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.scenarios import *

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        reset_demo_data()
```

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution. For simple stuff I will use the @wolendranh solution but remind I can handle it this way.